# ¿Cómo simplifico esta expresión para javascript?, estoy empezando

Tags: javascript, formulas

Tengo esta fórmula:

(30 * 1) = 30

(30 * 1) + (30 * 2) = 90

(30 * 1) + (30 * 2) + (30 * 3) = 180

¿Cómo hago para que me quede en una expresión simple para javascript sin usar tanto código y que sea cíclico?

Comment: Bienvenido seas, te recomiendo leer [ask], nos mostrarías lo que llevas al momento por favor

Comment: Cuál expresión? dónde está tu código javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar reduce.

```js
[1].reduce((acc, item) => acc + item*30, 0) // 30

[1,2].reduce((acc, item) => acc + item*30, 0) // 90

[1,2,3].reduce((acc, item) => acc + item*30, 0) // 180
```

De esa manera reusas la función `reduce` en el array de números que quieras sumar:

```js
const numeros = [los, números, que, quieras]
numeros.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item*30, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Algo asi te parece bien? :

```js
var numero_maximo = 5; //crea una variable de maxima lineas de calculo, en tu ejemplo seria 3
var texto = ""; //variable de texto para almacenar tu respuesta
var respuestas = 0; //almacena las soluciones a cada linea de calculo

for(var x=1;x<=numero_maximo;x++){//bucle que va de 1 a numero maximo para las respuestas

 for(var y=1;y<=x;y++){//segundo bucle que concatena los calculos en la variable texto y acumula el resultado final de dicho calculo. Va desde 1 hasta el valor de x.

    texto += "(30 * "+y+") + ";//acumulador del calculo en formato texto
           respuestas += (30*y);//suma las respuestas
        
 }   

    texto = texto.slice(0,-2);//se elimina el ultimo signo + y el ultimo espacio
    texto += " = " +respuestas+"<br/>";//se añade el signo = y la respuesta del calculo
    respuestas = 0;//se reinicia la variable respuestas

}

document.getElementById("xxx").innerHTML = texto; //se coloca el texto final
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="xxx"></p><!--aqui se coloca el resultado final-->

</body>
</html>
```